# Opera JS: XPath to find links that contain a path

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'm using Opera 11.50 and I have a JavaScript-function that works as a callback of an Ajax-request:

```
function nextPageCallback(responseText, responseXML) {
    if (responseXML && responseXML.documentElement) doc = responseXML.documentElement;
    else {
        doc = document.createElement("html");
        doc.innerHTML = responseText.replace(/[\n\r]/g, "").replace(/^.*\<html.*?\>|\<\/html.*$/i, "");
    }
    table = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")[1];

    if (table) {
        var trs;

        trs = document.evaluate("descendant::tr[count(td) > 1]", table, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

        for (var pos = 0; pos < trs.snapshotLength; pos++) {
            var tr = trs.snapshotItem(pos);
            var link;

            link = tr.innerHTML.match(/href=["'](\/path\/[^"']+?)["']/i)[1];
            linkX = document.evaluate("descendant::a[contains(@href, '/path/')]", tr, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea is to parse the `table` for certain links and then do something with the `A`- and `TR`-elements (further code is pointless for this issue and thus omitted).

The assignment to `trs` works, there are elements in the snapshot. The `TR`s will be moved around later so I need a snapshot.

The problem is with the last two lines. `link` is assigned by using plain old (error prone) RegEx and up to now works since there has been only one link that contains "/path/". Now `linkX` should end up with the same value. If you wonder why there's `STRING_TYPE`, well, nothing else works, not even `ANY_TYPE` (they all cause an `XPathException: TYPE_ERR`).

`linkX` is set to what seems to be the link text or `innerText` of the `A`-element. However, I want the `href`-attribute.

I already tried various things like using a namespace-resolver

```
function nsr() {
    return "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
}
:
            linkX = document.evaluate("descendant::a[contains(@href, '/path/')]", tr, nsr, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
```

but it isn't even called.

I also added more stuff at the end of the XPath like `/parent::node()`, but nothing works.

Does it have something to do that I'm using a DOM-structure that was returned by `document.evaluate()`? Is my XPath wrong? How do I fix this?

---

**EDIT**: As requested, here's a sample response that appears in `responseText`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Serialnumber</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Media</td>
        <td><a href="/path/2355">2355</a></td>
        <td>Sampler</td>
        <td>A65270-D32</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- more TRs of the structure above -->
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="/list/1">Previous</a>&nbsp;
          <a href="/list/3">Next</a>&nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regarding the code above it executes the `else`:

```
else {
    doc = document.createElement("html");
    doc.innerHTML = responseText.replace(/[\n\r]/g, "").replace(/^.*\<html.*?\>|\<\/html.*$/i, "");
}
```

What the code should do is find all `TR`s and in the `TR` the link containing "/path/". For further processing I need the `TR`-element and the `href`-attribute of `A`.

Comment: You haven't provided important and necessary data: 1) The XML document from which nodes should be selected. 2) Exactly which nodes you ant to be selected. Please, edit your question and provide the missing information.

Comment: @Dimitre updated as requested.

Comment: See my answer for a single XPath expression that selects exactly all the required nodes. As the provided XML document has a default namespace, you need first to associate a prefix to this namespace and then prefix all names in the expression. For more information search for XPath and default namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What the code should do is find all
>   `TR`s and in the `TR` the link containing
>   "/path/". For further processing I
>   need the `TR`-element and the
>   `href`-attribute of `A`.

**This XPath expression selects the wanted nodes**:

```
 //x:tr[//x:a[contains(@href, '/path/')]]
|
 //x:tr//x:a/@href[contains(.,'/path/')]
```

Here the prefix `x` must be associated to the (default) namespace `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.

Please, do note that XML and XPath are case-sensitive -- in the provided XML document there are no element with upper-case names.

Comment: Ah. Namespaces... They still scare me ;). However, a funny thing happened. I took your idea with the `.../@href[con...` and noticed that this worked: `descendant::a/@href[contains(., '/path/')]`. Note that I don't need the namespace you suggested. --- **If anyone reads this**: I'm marking this as the answer since it pointed me in the right direction and I believe that the suggested way may work for others. If it doesn't, try my way...